# Qt: How to get live output of a running QProcess

Tags: c++, qt

I have to get the output of a QProcess while it is running. Therefore I have written the following Code:

```
CommandExecutor_C::CommandExecutor_C():
  mProcessStatus(AI_UNKNOWN),
  mOnTdiActiveCallback(),
  mTdiProcess(new QProcess)
{
    connect(mTdiProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(CheckOutput()));
    connect(mTdiProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(CheckOutput()));
}

void CommandExecutor_C::ExecuteCommand(QString &aCommand)
{
  mTdiProcess->start(aCommand, QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
  LOGINFO(FB_TDI,"Launch command: " + aCommand.toStdString());
}


void CommandExecutor_C::CheckOutput()
{
    QString StdOut = QString(mTdiProcess->readAllStandardOutput());
    QString StdErr = QString(mTdiProcess->readAllStandardError());

    mProcessStatus = CheckTdiAutomationInterface(StdOut.toStdString(), StdErr.toStdString());

    if(mProcessStatus != AI_UNKNOWN)
    {
      OnTdiActive(mProcessStatus);
    }
}
```

This works fine if QProcess gets finished but in my case the Process starts an automation interface which should run in background permanently. Therefore I have used "readyReadStandardOutput" and connect it to the slot CheckOutput(). CheckOutput() is getting called just if the process has been finished. Otherwise I am waiting endless.

I have googled a lot about the problem but nothing worked. I am very sure that the output is getting buffered and does just return if the Process has finished. Therefore I have started the Process in Unbuffered-Mode. I have also tried to forward the channels of mTdiProcess. Here the Code:

```
void CommandExecutor_C::ExecuteCommand(QString &aCommand)
{
  mTdiProcess->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
  mTdiProcess->start(aCommand, QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
  LOGINFO(FB_TDI,"Launch command: " + aCommand.toStdString());
}
```

But nothing worked. I hope you can help me.

I am using Qt 5.4.2 if that's important.

Comment: Maybe you should stick to the signal `stateChanged()` because `readyReadStandardOutput()` seems not to be emitted in this situation which seems to be correct regarding to the documentation. If you want a `QProcess` which reports more often then create your own process class which inherits from `QProcess`. This would be a correct way I think.

Comment: It's possible that the actual process you're running (managed by the `QProcess` object) is also buffering its standard output. Are you sure that's not happening?

Comment: "If you want a QProcess which reports more often then create your own process class which inherits from QProcess." @maxik

Comment: That would be an idea but how? I don't know how to deactivate the buffering because QProcess::Unbuffered does not work. And I don't think that statechanged() would be the right signal because its made for a QCheckBox. Maybe bnaecker is right and the standard output is buffered. But how to check this?

Answer (score 4):

I usually check the output in regular intervals like this:

```
bool returnBool = false;
while (returnBool == false)
{
    /*! Wait one second if the process finishes. Then read all output to
     * stdout and stderr and redo. */
    returnBool = process.waitForFinished(1000);
    QString outputStdOut = process.readAllStandardOutput();
    QString outputStdErr = process.readAllStandardError();
}
```

Comment: I have tried something quit similar but it did not work in my case. And isn't that synchronously? I would suggest that the GUI will freeze while nothing was received. And its much better to use signals and slots instead like I have done because I am using a QProgressDialog (the bar does move from left to right while waiting).

Comment: You are right, that is synchronously. When you run this code from the GUI thread, it will freeze. If the signals work, then using them is of course better ...

Comment: this still not working in executables. but in other work. like pinging for example